# What happens to energy when a car runs into a wall?

Tags: energy

If a car drives into a wall and energy cannot escape to the environment, does all that energy that went into the wall get transferred back into the car? If so, is that why the car gets damaged?

Answer (score 0):

The energy is partially transferred to the wall and partially to the car. However saying that *this is why the car gets damaged* is a bad way to formulate it: the car gets damaged by the forces acting on it. Energy, while characterizing this process, is not identical with the process itself, and is not itself performing any action. Energy calculation is certainly a good way to estimate the amount of damage, e.g., by expressing it in kilograms of TNT.

Comment: Thanks! I asked this question because I'm doing a project on crumple zones of a car. One thing that crumple zones do is they make the collision less elastic, by making it so more of the kinetic energy is transformed into deformation energy, rather than being transferred to the wall. I'm having trouble putting why this is important into words. Why is it important to reduce the amount of kinetic energy that is transferred to the wall in a collision?

Comment: @joib Usually one wants the deformation to absorb more energy, so that there is less harm to the passangers. I can't say why one would protect the wall - perhaps to avoid it collapsing and causing more damage. Although I think a more realistic answer comes from the fact that the "wall" in the test actually represents another car in real life. You can see how transferring too much energy when rear-ending somebody may aggravate an accident.